# Apps not using full screen size

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

some apps not display full size (Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2)

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

What could be the reason, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I can fix it now . This happen when i install gltool.
I just  uninstall  it and apps fullscreen now.